# Change jquery datatable column settings value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change datatable column  settings value on fly.I need to hide some columns dynamically while invoking some methods.Already try something like this:

```
     var columns = [{ "bVisible":    true,  "sTitle": "Date" },
                    {"bVisible":    true, "sTitle": "Time" }];
     var myTable= $('#myTable').dataTable({
     "bPaginate": false,
     "bFilter": true,
     "sScrollY": "150px",
     "bRetrieve": true,
         "bProcessing": false,
         "bServerSide": false, 
         "aoColumns": columns,
         'bAutoWidth': false,
         "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {

          },
    });
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++ {
          myTable.fnAddData(['xxxx','yyyy']);
    }
    $("#hideDate").change(function() {
        myTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[0].bVisible = false;
     });
```

After calling hideDate change method I am getting this js error
TypeError: o.aoColumns[iVis] is undefined
    nThs[i].style.width = o.aoColumns[iVis].sWidth;

Please give some idea to fix this problem.
I need to change datatable columns visibility dynamically.

Regards,
Prasath M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a datatables plugin that has been created for this, [ColVis](https://datatables.net/extras/colvis/). If you don't want to use the plugin, you could look at the source code and see how they did it.